# They are right. And we are wrong

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, sherlock

In recently aired BBC Sherlock Season 4 Episode 0, when Sherlock goes to visit Mycroft on his call with John Watson. Mycroft tell them about taking a case. Relevant conversation is following:

> Watson : But these enemies. How are we to defeat them if you won't tell us about them?
>   Mycroft : We don't defeat them. We most certainly lose to them.
>   W : Why?
>   M : Because they are right. And we are wrong.

What does it mean? How were those "enemies" right ?

Comment: AFAIK this was not a Series 4 episode, BTW. Series 4 hasn't begun filming yet.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Yeah sorry...wikipedia called it '[Special 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_(TV_series)#Special_.282016.29)' and imdb called it [episode 0](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3845232/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marion Stein has [a good explanation](http://happynicetimepeople.com/sherlock-and-when-he-woke-up-bobby-ewing-was-in-the-shower-new-years-special/) over at Happy Nice Time People:

> They go to a “desanctified church” where **Mary announces she’s found
>   “the heart of the conspiracy.”** A group dressed in pointed sheets, not
>   white sheets but nevertheless clan-like, is chanting. Why the KKK
>   reference? It’s another nod to the source material, The Five Orange
>   Pips. Only here it isn’t southern white men hiding under the sheets.
>   **It’s British women, including Molly Hooper, and John’s housemaid –
>   women who’ve been abused, brutalized, and ignored.** Sherlock’s
>   fake-girlfriend from last season is there too. **They have become the
>   “invisible enemy” that Mycroft spoke about, and their cause is just.**
>
> Sherlock works it out. Mrs. Riccoletti was dying of tuberculosis. She
>   went on a suicide mission. First, she faked her death by appearing to
>   shoot herself in the head, but she really shot one of her guns at the
>   ground while a co-conspirator splashed blood on the back of her head.
>   A substitute corpse was taken to the morgue. Later, the real Mrs. R
>   killed her husband, and then shot herself. Her body replaced the
>   substitute. Thus **the legend of the vengeful ghost was born, and the
>   co-conspirators continued their mission to assassinate the brutes.**